# Which gives better quality SCART or S-VIDEO?

Tags: video-quality, video-capture, vhs

I have SVHS video cassetes and Panasonic NV-HS1000B. It has 2 outputs.
S-VIDEO and SCART.

There is any reason to use SCART and not the SVIDEO output?

I was googling but was confused. I read that SCART also carry a digital singal.

I'm also read this: [Does using an S-Video output via a SCART connector improve the output quality of a VCR?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29933/does-using-an-s-video-output-via-a-scart-connector-improve-the-output-quality-of)
But I didn't received a specific answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm a US-based broadcast engineer who hasn't worked on analog systems in long time, so I haven't had any direct experience with [SCART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART) connections. That said, there shouldn't be any difference in quality between S-Video out via a DIN connector or SCART on the same device. There's no difference in shielding, balancing, or signal between the two connectors. [This forum post](https://www.stereonet.com/forums/topic/164826-uec-dsd-720i-s-video-via-scart-vs-mini-din/) seems to agree. (Though it does sound like the device in that post has a termination issue, which might be something to check your VCR setup for.)

As best as I can tell, SCART never carries a digital signal. Some primarily professional devices (as noted in the [comments to the other question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29933/does-using-an-s-video-output-via-a-scart-connector-improve-the-output-quality-of#29936)), had RGB and color difference (YPbPr) component outputs which *might* have better quality and *might not* be available on a separate connector.